# RewriteRule after using wget

Tags: mod-rewrite, wget

I used wget to save entire website, as result I got files in this format:

```
book.asp@id=1005335&rbr=5.html
```

(this is an actual filename)

So now I'm having troubles doing RewriteRule

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^book\.asp$ /book@$1.html
```

This rule rewrites original query `/book.asp?id=1021278&rbr=0` to `/book@.html?id=1021278&rbr=0`

How do I get rid of ? and move .html to the end? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in the .htaccess file at root directory:

#### Here is the modified rule-set according to OP comments:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.html          [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.asp   /$1.asp@%{QUERY_STRING}.html? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. How to perform multiple of these rewrites correctly? By duplicating `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` lines to the end?

Comment: Are they so different? Give some requests examples to have an idea.

Comment: Just different file names like faq.asp, I know that `L` flag stops from processing any further.

Comment: Not really. But, I will update my answer with an option if that's all the difference.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but when request is just faq.asp (without query string - it fails). Should I add (*.+) to the end of regex?

Comment: What should happen when there is no query?

Comment: In other words, skip the rule. Right?

Comment: Amazing... The last one is weird, `[N]` flag applies only to request, but not the target. If original query is `/faq.asp@P=5` and filename is `faq.asp@p=5.html` - rule wont work.

Comment: You mean NC? If so, it applies only for the comparison. In no way means it changes the case.

Comment: Yes, sorry I mean `[NC]`. So I have to parse all htmls to change links to lowercase?

Comment: It is possible to force  lower or upper case with `RewriteMap` directive, but I guess that should be the subject of another question.

Comment: Let me know when you post the new question. I might be able to help.

Comment: I just renamed file to an uppercase `...P=5.html`, everything works perfectly now. This old site was on ASP 1.0/Win2k/IIS/MSSQL (crazy config). Moved to unix platform to keep search engine ratings. Added type .asp to httpd.conf as PHP mime-type. About 50000 files/links. Googlebot is happy now. =)